# Replace whole word matches only

Tags: php, replace, word-boundaries

I have been having a problem with the str_replace function, if I try to replace the word 'quote' it also replaces the matching part of the word 'quoted' which is not desired.

any suggestions ?

I am using glossary file to get the words from and pass it into an array, then open an html file that I need to modulate with glossary words.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) with a regular expression that takes the word boundary into account:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($word, '/').'\b/', 'replacement', $str);
```

Here `\b` are word boundary assertions. So the value of `$word` is only replaced if if occurs in `$str` with a word boundary before and after it.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to be more specific with preg_replace:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

If you need context sensitive replacement, you need to use regular expression version of replace() which is `preg_replace()`.

```
echo str_replace("quote", "NEWSTRING", $src_text);

echo preg_replace("/quote\b/", "NEWSTRING", $src_text);
```